# how to find the minimum number of primatics that sum to a given number

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming, primes

Given a number N (<=10000), find the minimum number of primatic numbers which sum up to N.

A primatic number refers to a number which is either a prime number or can be expressed as power of prime number to itself i.e. prime^prime e.g. 4, 27, etc.

I tried to  find all the primatic numbers using seive and then stored them in a vector (code below) but now I am can't see how to find the minimum of primatic numbers that sum to a given number.

Here's my sieve:

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>

#define MAX 10000

typedef long long int ll;

ll modpow(ll a, ll n, ll temp) {
    ll res=1, y=a;
    while (n>0) {
        if (n&1)
            res=(res*y)%temp;
        y=(y*y)%temp;
        n/=2;
    }
    return res%temp;
}


int isprimeat[MAX+20];

std::vector<int> primeat;

//Finding all prime numbers till 10000
void seive()
{
    ll i,j;
    isprimeat[0]=1;
    isprimeat[1]=1;
    for (i=2;  i<=MAX;  i++) {
        if (isprimeat[i]==0) {
            for (j=i*i;  j<=MAX;  j+=i) {
                isprimeat[j]=1;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i=2;  i<=MAX;  i++) {
        if (isprimeat[i]==0) {
            primeat.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    isprimeat[4]=isprimeat[27]=isprimeat[3125]=0;
    primeat.push_back(4);
    primeat.push_back(27);
    primeat.push_back(3125);
}

int main()
{
    seive();
    std::sort(primeat.begin(), primeat.end());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Please do my homework for me" is not a good Stack Overflow
question.  If you [edit] your question to describe what you
have tried so far and where you are stuck, then we can try
to help you to understand your specific problem. You should
also read [ask].

Comment: @TobySpeight this is the code(ideone link) i have done but as i am a newbie i don't know how to insert the code. its here on ideone http://ideone.com/E2Eozd

Comment: I've added the code from that link (minus unnecessary includes, unused variables and obfuscating macros).  HTH.

Comment: @TobySpeight thanks a lot can you please help me where can i learning editing on stackoverflow

Comment: @coder - If you have a question about editing that's not answered in [the help center](/editing-help), you should ask on [meta].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method could be to store all primatics less than or equal to N in a sorted list - call this list `L` - and recursively search for the shortest sequence. The easiest approach is "greedy": pick the largest spans / numbers as early as possible.

for `N = 14` you'd have `L = {2,3,4,5,7,8,9,11,13}`, so you'd want to make an algorithm / process that tries these sequences:

1. `13` is too small
2. `13 + 13` -> `13 + 2` will be too large
3. `11` is too small
4. `11 + 11` -> `11 + 4` will be too large
5. `11 + 3` is a match.

You can continue the process by making the search function recurse each time it needs another primatic in the sum, which you would aim to have occur a minimum number of times. To do so you can pick the largest -> smallest primatic in each position (the 1st, 2nd etc primatic in the sum), and include another number in the sum only if the primatics in the sum so far are small enough that an additional primatic won't go over `N`.

I'd have to make a working example to find a small enough `N` that doesn't result in just 2 numbers in the sum. Note that because you can express any natural number as the sum of at most 4 squares of natural numbers, and you have a more dense set `L` than the set of squares, so I'd think it rare you'd have a result of 3 or more for any `N` you'd want to compute by hand.

#### Dynamic Programming approach

I have to clarify that 'greedy' is not the same as 'dynamic programming', it can give sub-optimal results. This does have a DP solution though. Again, i won't write the final process in code but explain it as a point of reference to make a working DP solution from.

To do this we need to build up solutions from the bottom up. What you need is a structure that can store known solutions for all numbers up to some `N`, this list can be incrementally added to for larger `N` in an optimal way.

Consider that for any `N`, if it's primatic then the number of terms for `N` is just 1. This applies for `N=2-5,7-9,11,13,16,17,19`. The number of terms for all other `N` must be at least two, which means either it's a sum of two primatics or a sum of a primatic and *some other `N`*.

The first few examples that aren't trivial:

**6** - can be either `2+4` or `3+3`, all the terms here are themselves primatic so the minimum number of terms for 6 is 2.

**10** - can be either `2+8`, `3+7`, `4+6` or `5+5`. However 6 is not primatic, and taking that solution out leaves a minimum of 2 terms.

**12** - can be either `2+10`, `3+9`, `4+8`, `5+7` or `6+6`. Of these `6+6` and `2+10` contain non-primatics while the others do not, so again 2 terms is the minimum.

**14** - ditto, there exist two-primatic solutions: `3+11`, `5+9`, `7+7`.

The structure for storing all of these solutions needs to be able to iterate across solutions of equal rank / number of terms. You already have a list of primatics, this is also the list of solutions that need only one term.

`Sol[term_length] = list(numbers)`. You will also need a function / cache to look up some `N`'s shortest-term-length, eg `S(N) = term_length iif N in Sol[term_length]`

`Sol[1] = {2,3,4,5 ...}` and `Sol[2] = {6,10,12,14 ...}` and so on for `Sol[3]` and onwards.

Any solution can be found using one term from `Sol[1]` that is primatic. Any solution requiring two primatics will be found in `Sol[2]`. Any solution requiring 3 will be in `Sol[3]` etc.

What you need to recognize here is that a number `S(N) = 3` can be expressed `Sol[1][a] + Sol[1][b] + Sol[1][c]` for some `a,b,c` primatics, but it can also be expressed as `Sol[1][a] + Sol[2][d]`, since all `Sol[2]` must be expressible as `Sol[1][x] + Sol[1][y]`.

This algorithm will in effect search `Sol[1]` for a given `N`, then look in `Sol[1] + Sol[K]` with increasing `K`, but to do this you will need `S` and `Sol` structures roughly in the form shown here (or able to be accessed / queried in a similar manner).

#### Working Example

Using the above as a guideline I've put this together quickly, it even shows which multi-term sum it uses.

https://ideone.com/7mYXde

I can explain the code in-depth if you want but the real DP section is around lines 40-64. The recursion depth (also number of additional terms in the sum) is `k`, a simple dual-iterator while loop checks if a sum is possible using the kth known solutions and primatics, if it is then we're done and if not then check k+1 solutions, if any. `Sol` and `S` work as described.

The only confusing part might be the use of reverse iterators, it's just to make `!= end()` checking consistent for the while condition (end is not a valid iterator position but begin is, so `!= begin` would be written differently).

Edit - FYI, the first number that takes at least 3 terms is `959` - had to run my algorithm to 1000 numbers to find it. It's summed from 6 + 953 (primatic), no matter how you split 6 it's still 3 terms.

Comment: is it possible to do it with dp @Xeren

Comment: @coder I've updated my answer but I still think there's an even better way to do it. I might add a code example there to show it in action.

Comment: @coder it's simple enough to implement, i've added a working example.

Comment: @ Xeren thanks a lot for such a beautiful explanation :) I am a big fan of you :) sorry for late reply as i was busy with publication of  my app.